# Groupby values using boolean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, pandas-groupby

```py
df['check'] = ((df['id'] == 123) & (df['date1'] >= date1)) | ((df['id'] == 456) & (df['date2'] >= date2))

present = df.groupby(['id', 'month', 'check'])['userid'].nunique().reset_index(name="usercount")
```

This is my code, so my expected output must have number of unique users per month in the column `usercount`
grouped by `id`. i used `id`, `month` and `check` in `groupby`.

The `check` column is type `bool`, based on first line of my code, but when i got output from `present` dataframe, the users are counted who has `check` value as `True`, also who has as `False`.

Actually, it should count the users who have only `True` in `check` column.

help me out in this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need filter by `check` column by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), not pass to `by` parameter in `groupby`:

```
#first convert datetimes to start of months
df['month'] = df['month'].dt.floor('d') - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
print (df)
   check      month   id userid
0   True 2019-06-01  123      a
1  False 2019-02-01  123      b
2  False 2019-01-01  123      c
3  False 2019-02-01  123      d
4   True 2019-06-01  123      e
5   True 2020-07-01  123      f
6   True 2020-07-01  123      g
7   True 2020-06-01  123      h

print (df[df['check']])
   check      month   id userid
0   True 2019-06-01  123      a
4   True 2019-06-01  123      e
5   True 2020-07-01  123      f
6   True 2020-07-01  123      g
7   True 2020-06-01  123      h

present = (df[df['check']].groupby(['id', 'month'])['userid']
                          .nunique()
                          .reset_index(name="usercount"))
print (present)
    id      month  usercount
0  123 2019-06-01          2
1  123 2020-06-01          1
2  123 2020-07-01          2
```

Comment: @Beginner - Can you add some data sample, expected output for see what is wrong? Without data hard to know

Comment: I have attached an image explaining my question. It should count for each **id** for each **month** which has **only True** value in **check column**, but I got output including **False** value.

Comment: @Beginner - It is weird, do you use `df[df['check']]` before groupby ? Answer was edited.